# PowerShell match expression

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have the following text output in PowerShell derived from running `netsh wlan show networks`

```
SSID 1 : LSOX
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP 

SSID 2 : Embers_2ghz
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP 

SSID 3 : BRIGHTON_LEVEL1
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP 

SSID 4 : BRIGHTON_LEVEL2
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP 

SSID 5 : BRIGHTON_PRODUCTION
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP
```

This is what PowerShell I have now, but doesn't do what I want: `(netsh wlan show networks) | Select-String -Pattern "(SSID .* : ?)" | % { $_.Matches[0].Value }`

Using some sort of `Select-String -Pattern` expression I want to list only the names, so the output would be:

```
LSOX
Embers_2ghz
BRIGHTON_LEVEL1
BRIGHTON_LEVEL2
BRIGHTON_PRODUCTION
```

I am great at PowerShell, but crap at expressions, although I find them fascinating, here is one site I have been referencing http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/06/chapter-13-text-and-regular-expressions.aspx#regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked it out.....

This seems to work:

```
(netsh wlan show networks) | Select-String -Pattern "(?<=SSID . : ).+" | % { $_.Matches[0].Value }
```

Comment: This assumes that the SSID is a single digit. You can cater for more via a pattern like "(?<=SSID \d+ : ).+".